# Why does pandas apply calculate twice

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I'm using the apply method on a panda's DataFrame object.  When my DataFrame has a single column, it appears that the applied function is being called twice.  The questions are why? And, can I stop that behavior?

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

def mul2(x):
    print ('hello')
    return 2*x

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,0.67,1.34]})
df.apply(mul2)
```

**Output:**

```
hello
hello

0  2.00
1  4.00
2  1.34
3  2.68
```

I'm printing 'hello' from within the function being applied.  I know it's being applied twice because 'hello' printed twice.  What's more is that if I had two columns, 'hello' prints 3 times.  Even more still is when I call applied to just the column 'hello' prints 4 times.

**Code:**

```
df.a.apply(mul2)
```

**Output:**

```
hello
hello
hello
hello
0    2.00
1    4.00
2    1.34
3    2.68
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### This behavior has been fixed with pandas 1.1, please upgrade!

Now, **[`apply` and `applymap` on DataFrame evaluates first row/column only once](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html#apply-and-applymap-on-dataframe-evaluates-first-row-column-only-once)**.

Initially, we had `GroupBy.apply` and `Series/df.apply` evaluating the first group twice. The reason the first group is evaluated twice is because apply wants to know whether it can "optimize" the calculation (sometimes this is possible if apply receives a numpy or cythonized function). With pandas 0.25, [this behavior was fixed for GroupBy.apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390035/pandas-groupby-apply-method-duplicates-first-group). Now, with pandas 1.1, this will also be fixed for df.apply.

---

**Old Behavior** [pandas <= 1.0.X]

```
pd.__version__ 
# '1.0.4'

df.apply(mul2)
hello
hello

      a
0  2.00
1  4.00
2  1.34
3  2.68
```

**New Behavior** [pandas >= 1.1]

```
pd.__version__
# '1.1.0.dev0+2004.g8d10bfb6f'

df.apply(mul2)
hello

      a
0  2.00
1  4.00
2  1.34
3  2.68
```

Comment: I mean look at that reputation score... gratz on 200k!  Nice to see you around.

Comment: @piRSquared yessir, it's been a while! Was hoping to catch you on chat the other day but you're not pingable anymore :(

Comment: I haven't been on chat.  Working from home with only one monitor.  I can't afford the real estate for a chat window... so I forget to open it /-:

Comment: @piRSquared and gratz to you on 200 as well. Really miss seeing those piR-esque answers popping up every now and then. PS when I answered this I didn't notice who the asker was initially. Came as nothing but a pleasant surprise when I did. Stay safe!

Comment: @cs95, I'm facing an issue which is not solved even in `1.1.0` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63400773/pandas-1-1-0-misses-second-row-in-df-apply

Comment: See the post from Lucas. It's a bug in apply that updates the row inplace.

Comment: I'm on version 1.4.4 and `groupby.apply` is calling the function twice for EACH group!

Answer (score 16):

This behavior is intended, as an optimization.

See the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

> In the current implementation apply calls func twice on the first
>   column/row to decide whether it can take a fast or slow code path.
>   This can lead to unexpected behavior if func has side-effects, as they
>   will take effect twice for the first column/row.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I don't know and I think not.  Simply because it's thought of as and optimization.

Comment: Apparently >= 0.25.0 has fixed this.

Comment: >= 0.25.0 no longer has apply twice on groupby combinator: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/24748#issuecomment-532148732 But normal `apply` still does has a double execution.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai From 1.1 the behavior has been amended for df.apply as well, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62893120/4909087) for more.

Answer (score 13):

Probably related to [this issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2656).  With groupby, the applied function is called one extra time to see if certain optimizations can be done.  I'd guess something similar is going on here.  It doesn't look like there's any way around it at the moment (although I could be wrong about the source of the behavior you're seeing).  Is there a reason you need it to not do that extra call.

Also, calling it four times when you apply on the column is normal.  When you get one columnm you get a Series, not a DataFrame.  `apply` on a Series applies the function to each *element*.  Since your column has four elements in it, the function is called four times.

Comment: The function I'm using is recursive.  I'm trying to avoid it doing the recursive calculation more than it needs to.  Right now, its not an issue, but it could be.