# Pandas Apply processing more rows than existing dataframe

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, database-connection

I have a Pandas dataframe very simple it's shape is (140, 10) but when I use:

`df.apply(lambda row: somefunction(row, otherparameter),  axis=1)`

It's doubling the first row on the dataframe, to prove this I used a print inside of **somefunction** that prints the row.

the only strange thing that I am doing inside **somefunction** is inserting a record to a database (but the print is before this instruction so it has nothing to do with it or I believe so). there is some reason why I don't want to use `to_sql` function but is another option.

when I check the dataframe shape after the apply line, the shape continues to be the same.

I would like to know possible causes of this

Comment: [This question has already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31877909/pandas-function-dataframe-apply-runs-top-row-twice), but I would like to know any workaround to this behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will most likely work slower than "ordinary" *apply*,
but you can try *iterrows()*. Something like:

```
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    somefunction(row, otherparameter)
```

The first result from *iterrows* is the index of the current row.
If you don't need it, replace *ind* with *_*.

Comment: I will mark this as the accepted answer, I'm a bit concerned about performance here but your solution works