# df.iloc[0:1,:].apply(func, axis=1, x,y,z) executes func() 2 times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe df that has thousands of rows.

For each row I want to apply function func.

As a test, I wanted to run func for only the first row of df. In `func()` I placed a print statement. I realized that the print statement was run 2 times even though I am slicing df to one row (there is an additional row for columns but those are columns).

When I do the following

```
df[0:1].apply(func, axis=1, x,y,z)
```

or

```
df.iloc[0:1,:].apply(func, axis=1, x,y,z)
```

The print statement is run 2 times, which means `func()` was executed twice.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does pandas apply calculate twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635915/why-does-pandas-apply-calculate-twice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) clearly says:

> In the current implementation apply calls func twice on the first column/row to decide whether it can take a fast or slow code path.

Comment: Ah, okay so calls to func 2 times only for the first column/row (in my case row).

Answer (score 0):

pay attention at different slicing techniques:

```
In [134]: df
Out[134]:
   a  b  c
0  9  5  4
1  4  7  2
2  1  3  7
3  6  3  2
4  4  5  2

In [135]: df.iloc[0:1]
Out[135]:
   a  b  c
0  9  5  4

In [136]: df.loc[0:1]
Out[136]:
   a  b  c
0  9  5  4
1  4  7  2
```

with printing:

print one row as Series:

```
In [139]: df[0:1].apply(lambda r: print(r), axis=1)
a    9
b    5
c    4
Name: 0, dtype: int32
Out[139]:
0    None
dtype: object
```

or using `iloc`:

```
In [144]: df.iloc[0:1, :].apply(lambda r: print(r), axis=1)
a    9
b    5
c    4
Name: 0, dtype: int32
Out[144]:
0    None
dtype: object
```

print two rows/Series:

```
In [140]: df.loc[0:1].apply(lambda r: print(r), axis=1)
a    9
b    5
c    4
Name: 0, dtype: int32
a    4
b    7
c    2
Name: 1, dtype: int32
Out[140]:
0    None
1    None
dtype: object
```

OP:

> "the print statement was run 2 times even though I am slicing df to
>   one row"

actually, you were *slicing* it into two rows

Comment: I'm not running df.loc[0:1]. I'm running df[0:1] which is = df.loc[0:1,:]

Comment: Oops. I made a mistake in my OP. Its df.iloc[0:1,:] not df.loc[0:1,:]

Comment: @codingknob, both `df[0:1].apply()` and `df.iloc[0:1, :].apply()` should work properly, as i described in my answer

Comment: Strange. The result of df[0:1] and df.iloc[0:1,:] for me is the first row of df in my case as a dataframe object and not a series.

Comment: @codingknob, that's why you should always provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking a question