# Group lists of different rows by multiple columns values with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, sum

I have a dataframe `df1` like this:

```
import pandas as pd
dic = {'A':[0,0,2,2,2,1,5,5],'B':[[1,5,3,8],[1,8,7,5],[7,8,9,5],[3],[1,5,9,3],[0,3,5],[],[4,2,3,1]],'C':['a','b','c','c','d','e','f','f'],'D':['0','8','7','6','4','5','2','2']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

and looks like this:

```
#Initial dataframe 
   A             B  C  D
0  0  [1, 5, 3, 8]  a  0
1  0  [1, 8, 7, 5]  b  8
2  2  [7, 8, 9, 5]  c  7
3  2           [3]  c  6
4  2  [1, 5, 9, 3]  d  4
5  1     [0, 3, 5]  e  5
6  5            []  f  2
7  5  [4, 2, 3, 1]  f  2
```

My goal is to group rows that have the same values in column `A` and `C` and merge the content of column `B` in such a way that the result looks like this:

```
#My GOAL
   A                B  C
0  0     [1, 5, 3, 8]  a
1  0     [1, 8, 7, 5]  b
2  2  [3, 7, 8, 9, 5]  c
3  2     [1, 5, 9, 3]  d
4  1        [0, 3, 5]  e
5  5     [4, 2, 3, 1]  f
```

As you can see, rows having the same items in column `A` and `C` are merged while if at least one is different they are left as is.
My idea was to use the `groupby` and `sum` functions like this:

```
df1.groupby(by=['A','C'],as_index=False,sort=True).sum()
```

but Python returns an error message: `Function does not reduce`

Could you please tell me what is wrong with my line of code? What should I write in order to achieve my goal?

Note: I do not care about what happens to column `D` which can be discarted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the possibilities would be to flatten the `list` of lists until it gets exhausted with the help of [**`itertools.chain(*iterables)`**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
import itertools
df1.groupby(['A', 'C'])['B'].apply(lambda x: list(itertools.chain(*x))).reset_index()
```

***(Or)***

Use `sum` with `lambda`:

```
df1.groupby(by=['A','C'])['B'].apply(lambda x: x.sum()).reset_index()
```

Both yield:

[image]

By default, `groupby().sum()` looks for numeric types (scalar) values to perform aggregation and not a collection of elements like `list` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
df1.groupby(by=['A','C'],as_index=False,sort=True).agg({'B': lambda x: tuple(sum(x, []))})
```

Result:

```
   A  C                B
0  0  a     (1, 5, 3, 8)
1  0  b     (1, 8, 7, 5)
2  1  e        (0, 3, 5)
3  2  c  (7, 8, 9, 5, 3)
4  2  d     (1, 5, 9, 3)
5  5  f     (4, 2, 3, 1)
```

Based in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29848546/1782792) (it seems that lists do not work too well with aggregation).