# Pandas pivot_table with aggfunc works differently on little different data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of *Date*, *Buy*, and *Sell* values and doing a `pivot_table` on that dataframe to get all Buy/Sell value of each date which works.

```
data = [('20170325', 'Buy', 400 ),
        ('20170325', 'Buy', 401 ),
        ('20170323', 'Buy', 400 ),
        ('20170324', 'Sell', 400 )]

testDf = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'Scenario', 'Value'])
df1 = pd.pivot_table(testDf, columns='Scenario', index='Date', values='Value', 
                     fill_value = '', aggfunc=lambda x: x.tolist() if len(x)>1 else x)
df1
#    Scenario         Buy Sell
#    Date                     
#    20170323         400     
#    20170324              400
#    20170325  [400, 401]
```

But when my data changes a bit, `pivot_table` throws error: *ValueError: Function does not reduce*. Not able to understand why. Here is the error with different data. Please note that *Date* of *20170325* is changed to *20170321*.

```
data = [('20170321', 'Buy', 400 ),
        ('20170321', 'Buy', 401 ),
        ('20170323', 'Buy', 400 ),
        ('20170324', 'Sell', 400 )]

testDf = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'Scenario', 'Value'])
df1 = pd.pivot_table(testDf, columns='Scenario', index='Date', values='Value', 
                     fill_value = '',aggfunc=lambda x: x.tolist() if len(x)>1 else x)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in 
>   
>  File
>   "ext2\vc12_win32\lib\python2.7\site-packages\pandas\tools\pivot.py",
>   line 114, in pivot_table 
>  File
>   "ext2\vc12_win32\lib\python2.7\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py",
>   line 729, in agg 
>  File
>   "ext2\vc12_win32\lib\python2.7\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py",
>   line 2978, in aggregate 
>  File
>   "ext2\vc12_win32\lib\python2.7\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py",
>   line 1227, in _python_agg_general 
>  File
>   "ext2\vc12_win32\lib\python2.7\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py",
>   line 1733, in agg_series 
>  File
>   "ext2\vc12_win32\lib\python2.7\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py",
>   line 1767, in _aggregate_series_pure_python  
>  ValueError:
>   Function does not reduce

Comment: As @ScottBoston mentions below, that error occurs on both datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Consider even a `groupby` with `pivot`:

```
df1 = testDf.groupby(['Date', 'Scenario'])['Value'].apply(lambda x: list(x)).reset_index()\
            .pivot(index='Date', columns='Scenario', values='Value').fillna('')

# Scenario         Buy   Sell
# Date                       
# 20170323       [400]       
# 20170324              [400]
# 20170325  [400, 401]       

# Scenario         Buy   Sell
# Date                       
# 20170321  [400, 401]       
# 20170323       [400]       
# 20170324              [400]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with your first dataset also.  I believe this is due to the duplicate values on a day.

This appears to be a feature of pandas from this SO [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27439023/pandas-groupby-agg-function-does-not-reduce)

Let's try to convert your tolist() to use tuple instead.

```
df1 = pd.pivot_table(testDf, columns='Scenario', index='Date', values='Value', fill_value = '',aggfunc=lambda x: tuple(x))
```

Comment: But one idea, if use `lambda x: tuple(x) if len(x)>1 else x)` How does it work?

Comment: I don't think it will work because of mixed types maybe and still not reducing.  Nope that conditional at the end kills it also.

Comment: @ScottBoston Tuple works. But wondering why list does not. Strange that I am not getting any error with my first data set. May be something to do with pandas version? I am using v0.17.1.

Comment: @ScottBoston Further looking at the last comment of the post you shared, found that "This is a misfeature in DataFrame. If the aggregator returns a list for the first group, it will fail with the error you mention; if it returns a non-list (non-Series) for the first group, it will work fine."

This kind of explains the behavior I am seeing. pivot_table sorts the index involved. In my first dataset first group is with date '20170323' and aggregator returns single value. Hence, it works. For my second dataset first group is with date '20170321' and aggregator returns a list. Hence the error.