# Python pandas groupby object apply method adds index

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, group-by

I have this question is an extension after reading the ["Python pandas groupby object apply method duplicates first group"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390035/python-pandas-groupby-object-apply-method-duplicates-first-group).

I get the answer, and tried some experiments on my own, e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
from cStringIO import StringIO
s = '''c1 c2 c3
1 2 3
4 5 6'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=' ')
print df
def f2(df):
    print df.iloc[:]
    print "--------"
    return df.iloc[:]
df2 = df.groupby(['c1']).apply(f2)
print "======"
print df2
```

gives as expected:

```
   c1  c2  c3
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
   c1  c2  c3
0   1   2   3
--------
   c1  c2  c3
0   1   2   3
--------
   c1  c2  c3
1   4   5   6
--------
======
   c1  c2  c3
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
```

However, when I try to return only df.iloc[0]:

```
def f3(df):
    print df.iloc[0:]
    print "--------"
    return df.iloc[0:]
df3 = df.groupby(['c1']).apply(f3)
print "======"
print df3
```

, I get an additional index:

```
   c1  c2  c3
0   1   2   3
--------
   c1  c2  c3
0   1   2   3
--------
   c1  c2  c3
1   4   5   6
--------
======
      c1  c2  c3
c1              
1  0   1   2   3
4  1   4   5   6
```

I did some search and suspect this may mean there is a different code path taken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `iloc[:]` returns the object itself, while `iloc[0:]` returns a view of the object. Take a look at this:

```
>>> df.iloc[:] is df
True

>>> df.iloc[0:] is df
False
```

Where this makes a difference is that within the groupby, each group has a `name` attribute that reflects the grouping. When your function returns an object with this `name` attribute, no index is added to the result, while if you return an object without this `name` attribute, an index is added to track which group each came from.

Interestingly, you can *force* the `iloc[:]` behavior for `iloc[0:]` by explicitly setting the `name` attribute of the group before returning:

```
def f(x):
    out = x.iloc[0:]
    out.name = x.name
    return out

df.groupby('c1').apply(f)
#    c1  c2  c3
# 0   1   2   3
# 1   4   5   6
```

My guess is that the no-index behavior with named output is basically a special case meant to make `df.groupby(col).apply(lambda x: x)` be a no-op.

Comment: Seems exactly right (also tried out= x.iloc[0:1]; out.name = x.name , and got the extra index). Also, cool video on the Scikit-Learn, you rock :)

Comment: Also tried out= x.iloc[0:1]; out.name = x.name , and got the extra index, but only if the returned result would differ when there are duplicate c1 values.