# DataFrame groupby().apply() function seems to be called twice

Tags: dataframe, group-by, apply

Here is a simple DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np
dd=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(35).reshape(7,5), columns=list('xyzwv'))
dd['w']=list('AABBBCC')
```

,which is:

[image]

Now I try the following code

```
def func(x):
    print(x)
    return x

dd.groupby('w').apply(func)
```

then it prints out:

[image]

I think something goes wrong because
[image] is being printed twice.

It looks as if func() is being called twice for the same group.
What mistake did I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas GroupBy.apply method duplicates first group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390035/pandas-groupby-apply-method-duplicates-first-group)

Answer (score 2):

`apply` calls the first group twice to work out whether it could do some optimizations, see
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply

Comment: I don't see any optimization related notes from the link you give. But I think calling twice for that reason makes sense. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Royalblue This answer is no longer correct for versions of pandas from 0.25 [Groupby.apply on DataFrame evaluates first group only once](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#groupby-apply-on-dataframe-evaluates-first-group-only-once)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney  I am on panda 1.4.4 and it is still called twice ... on EACH group!