# pandas dataframe: groupby will give duplicate groupby

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a working example

```
# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":range(10), "b":[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,1]})
# group by 'b' column and print every group
df.groupby("b").apply(lambda x:print(x))
```

***Here is the result, as you can see, the first 2 group contains the same elements. How do I correct this?***

```
   a  b
0  0  1
1  1  1
2  2  1
9  9  1

   a  b
0  0  1
1  1  1
2  2  1
9  9  1

   a  b
3  3  2
4  4  2
5  5  2

   a  b
6  6  3
7  7  3

   a  b
8  8  4
```

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21390035/2901002)

Comment: You haven't actually shown your `groupby` code

Comment: @FujiAple, I am sorry. I should check my question before post it.