# Duplicate group appearing in pandas.GroupByDataFrame.apply operation

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a dataframe that looks like this:

```
>>> df
   A  B   C
0  1  4  10
1  2  5  11
2  3  6  12
3  1  7  13
4  2  8  14
5  3  9  15
6  1  4  16
7  2  5  17
8  3  6  18
```

Next, consider creating a `DataFrameGroupBy` object grouping the dataframe by the 'A' column using the pandas `DataFrame.groupby` function. Finally, we will apply the following user defined function to the DataFrameGroupBy object using the DataFrameGroupBy.apply method:

```
>>> def do_group_stuff(grp,grpname):
...     print(f"grpname: {grpname}")
...     grp.apply(lambda row: print(row),axis=1)
>>> df.groupby(['A']).apply(lambda grp: do_group_stuff(grp,grp.name))
```

I expect there to be three groups in the DataFrameGroupBy object corresponding to the three values seen in the 'A' column of df and the output to look something like this:

```
grpname: 1
A     1
B     4
C    10
Name: 0, dtype: int64
A     1
B     7
C    13
Name: 3, dtype: int64
A     1
B     4
C    16
Name: 6, dtype: int64
grpname: 2
A     2
B     5
C    11
Name: 1, dtype: int64
A     2
B     8
C    14
Name: 4, dtype: int64
A     2
B     5
C    17
Name: 7, dtype: int64
grpname: 3
A     3
B     6
C    12
Name: 2, dtype: int64
A     3
B     9
C    15
Name: 5, dtype: int64
A     3
B     6
C    18
```

But in reality the output looks like this:

```
grpname: 1
A     1
B     4
C    10
Name: 0, dtype: int64
A     1
B     7
C    13
Name: 3, dtype: int64
A     1
B     4
C    16
Name: 6, dtype: int64
grpname: 1
A     1
B     4
C    10
Name: 0, dtype: int64
A     1
B     7
C    13
Name: 3, dtype: int64
A     1
B     4
C    16
Name: 6, dtype: int64
grpname: 2
A     2
B     5
C    11
Name: 1, dtype: int64
A     2
B     8
C    14
Name: 4, dtype: int64
A     2
B     5
C    17
Name: 7, dtype: int64
grpname: 3
A     3
B     6
C    12
Name: 2, dtype: int64
A     3
B     9
C    15
Name: 5, dtype: int64
A     3
B     6
C    18
```

where the "1" group is repeate twice for some reason. Any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: That is bug for apply

Comment: I think you are seeing the optimization pass. 
 This first pass is not recorded in the returned dataset, but the function is called, so prints show up twice.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25716383/6361531