# Pandas's apply: first row elaborated twice

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

- Pandas 1.0.5
- Python 3.8.0
- Numpy 1.19.0

This code behaves strange:

```
import pandas as pd

def calc(row):
    print(f"Row: {row.to_list()}")
    result = pd.Series({
        "sum1": row.col1 + row.col2,
        "sum2": row.col2 + row.col3,
        "sum3": row.col1 + row.col3,
    })
    return result
    
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3], 
                   "col2":[4,5,6], 
                   "col3":[7,8,9]})

df[["sum12", "sum23", "sum13"]] = df.apply(lambda row: calc(row), axis=1)
print(df)
```

It returns

```
Row: [1, 4, 7]
Row: [1, 4, 7]
Row: [2, 5, 8]
Row: [3, 6, 9]

    col1    col2    col3    sum12   sum23   sum13
0    1       4       7       5       11      8
1    2       5       8       7       13     10
2    3       6       9       9       15     12
```

**First question:**

Why is the first row elaborated twice?

**Second question** possibly linked to the first:

In my real code the elaboration of the first row takes 0.15 seconds (read by `time.process_time()`), the following rows between 0.53 and 0.60. The first row is elaborated twice, first time 0.15 secs, second time 0.55 secs.

What could be the reason, as data are uniform, only `numpy` is used in `calc()`, and there are no conditionals nor data filters involved?

Comment: First (and most obvious) question, what is your pandas version? [This is a known issue and has been fixed in pandas 0.25](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56215416/4909087).

Comment: Added versions. I am working with the most recent ones. It looks like the bug has not been solved completely, or it is unrelated to `group`. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Oops, just fact checking myself: that link was for groupby.apply only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with both `GroupBy.apply` (pandas < 0.25) and `df.apply` (pandas < 1.1). The reason the first group is evaluated twice is because `apply` wants to know whether it can "optimize" the calculation (sometimes this is possible if `apply` receives a numpy or cythonized function).

With pandas 0.25, this behavior was fixed for `GroupBy.apply`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390035/pandas-groupby-apply-method-duplicates-first-group). Now with pandas 1.1, [the same behavior will be fixed for `df.apply`.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html#apply-and-applymap-on-dataframe-evaluates-first-row-column-only-once)

When 1.1 is out, you'll be able to upgrade and then you will only see the first group evaluated only once:

```
pd.__version__
# '1.1.0.dev0+2004.g8d10bfb6f'

df[["sum12", "sum23", "sum13"]] = df.apply(lambda row: calc(row), axis=1)
print(df)
Row: [1, 4, 7]
Row: [2, 5, 8]
Row: [3, 6, 9]
   col1  col2  col3  sum12  sum23  sum13
0     1     4     7      5     11      8
1     2     5     8      7     13     10
2     3     6     9      9     15     12
```

Comment: Thank you. It sound reasonable. BUt why the following executions takes LONGER then? I used a single execution to elaborate the calculations, and then saw that the real loop takes 5 times longer :-(

Comment: @AlexPoca I'm not a pandas dev, so your guess is as good as mine. It may have something to do with pandas testing for possible fastpaths in the code. It could also be linked to caching, if the second time is shorter than the first. Etc.